# Converting numbers to date format dd/mm/yyyy in a column until empty cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date

So I have got the below code working for a specific range of cells. But I want the macro to work for different range sizes. I basically need the code to go through each cell until it reaches an empty cell. The second part of the code I have been able to do this, but changing the first half is a bit more tricky. Can anyone help?

```
Sub OldestDateComplete()

Sheets(1).Activate

Dim l As String
Dim testdate As String
Dim ConvertDate As Date
Dim k As Integer

For k = 3 To 7
l = Sheets(1).Cells(k, 9).Value

testdate = CStr(l)

dotdate = False
If InStr(testdate, ".") Then dotdate = True
If dotdate = False Then ConvertDate = DateValue(CInt(Left(testdate, Len  (testdate) - 6)) & "/" & CInt(Mid(testdate, Len(testdate) - 5, 2)) & "/" & CInt(Right(testdate, 4)))
If dotdate = True Then ConvertDate = DateValue(CInt(Left(testdate, Len(testdate) - 8)) & "/" & CInt(Mid(testdate, Len(testdate) - 6, 2)) & "/" & CInt(Right(testdate, 4)))

Sheets(1).Cells(k, 9) = ConvertDate

Next k


Range(Range("I3"), Range("I3").End(xlDown)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("I3"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range(Range("I3"), Range("I3").End(xlDown))
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Range("I3").Select
Selection.Copy
Sheets("Sheet2").Select
Range("AA1").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do it, this one is the easiest...

```
lastrow = Range("I1048576").End(xlUp).Row    
For k = 3 To lastrow
l = Sheets(1).Cells(k, 9).Value

testdate = CStr(l)

dotdate = False
If InStr(testdate, ".") Then dotdate = True
If dotdate = False Then ConvertDate = DateValue(CInt(Left(testdate, Len  (testdate) - 6)) & "/" & CInt(Mid(testdate, Len(testdate) - 5, 2)) & "/" & CInt(Right(testdate, 4)))
If dotdate = True Then ConvertDate = DateValue(CInt(Left(testdate, Len(testdate) - 8)) & "/" & CInt(Mid(testdate, Len(testdate) - 6, 2)) & "/" & CInt(Right(testdate, 4)))

Sheets(1).Cells(k, 9) = ConvertDate

Next k
```

Comment: Works perfectly now! I knew there would be a simple solution, but could not think. Thank you